# Error al procesar PHP

Tags: php

al procesar mi formulario de php todo se inserta bien en las tablas de la base de datos pero se queda la pantalla de color blanco, el procesar.php no me ejecuta el alert.

Este es mi procesar.php

```
<?php
require("conexion.php");
$conexion=conectar();

  $refen_preml=$_POST['refen_preml'];
  $fecha_compre=$_POST['fecha_compre'];
  $hora_compre=$_POST['hora_compre'];
  $nom_operador=$_POST['nom_operador'];
  $menssagge=$_POST['menssagge'];



    $sql="INSERT INTO pre_materiales (refen_preml,fecha_compre,hora_compre,nom_operador,menssagge) 
            VALUES ('".$refen_preml."','".$fecha_compre."','".$hora_compre."','".$nom_operador."','".$menssagge."')";

            $ok=mysqli_query($sql,$conexion);






  $id_preguntas=$_POST['id'];
  $pregunta=$_POST['pregunta'];
  $stock=$_POST['stock'];
  $uni=$_POST['uni'];
  $comentario=$_POST['comentario'];
  $comentariotwo=$_POST['comentariotwo'];
  $comentariotree=$_POST['comentariotree'];
  $comentariofour=$_POST['comentariofour'];
  $area_pregunta=$_POST['area_pregunta'];



for($i = 0; $i < count($pregunta); $i++){

       $id_preguntas[$i];
       $pregunta[$i];
       $stock[$i];
       $uni[$i];
       $comentario[$i];
       $comentariotwo[$i];
       $comentariotree[$i];
       $comentariofour[$i];
       $area_pregunta[$i];




            $sql1="INSERT INTO resp_materiales (refen_preml,id_preguntas,pregunta,stock,uni,comentario,comentariotwo,comentariotree,comentariofour,area_pregunta) 
            VALUES ('".$refen_preml."','".$id_preguntas[$i]."','".$pregunta[$i]."','".$stock[$i]."','".$uni[$i]."','".$comentario[$i]."','".$comentariotwo[$i]."','".$comentariotree[$i]."','".$comentariofour[$i]."','".$area_pregunta[$i]."')";

            $ok1=mysqli_query($sql1,$conexion);




    }




    if ($ok)
    {
echo"<script type='text/javascript'>
        alert('El registro se realizo correctamente');
        window.location='firmafive.php?refen_preml=$refen_preml&nom_operador=$nom_operador;
        </script>";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "<script>alert('Ya existe el ID de esta Inspección')
    window.location='materiales.php';</script>";
    }


?>
```

El codigo funciona bien porque revise mi base de datos y esta insertando los registros, pero en el navegador se queda en procesar.php no me muestra el alert, que podria ser el error?

Saludos.

Comment: En la consola te da algún error ?

Comment: @DarkFrostnight no da ningun error solo queda pantalla blanca, pero si inserta todos los datos en las tablas, no ejecuta el alert.

Comment: @DarkFrostnight ahora si da este error en la consola: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: Creo que en ese mensaje pone que token fue el que no esperaba. Lo colocaste completo, voy a intentar replicar con tu código a ver que pasa.

Comment: falta un ' en una linea, te deje la respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te falta una `'`

deberías tener esto:

```
window.location='firmafive.php?refen_preml=$refen_preml&nom_operador=$nom_operador';
```

Te dejo el código completo de esa sección:

```
if ($ok)
    {
echo"<script type='text/javascript'>
        alert('El registro se realizo correctamente');
        window.location='firmafive.php?refen_preml=$refen_preml&nom_operador=$nom_operador';
        </script>";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "<script>alert('Ya existe el ID de esta Inspección')
    window.location='materiales.php';</script>";
    }
```

Comment: Ya agregue la ' pero ahora intento guardar otro registro y me sale el segundo mensaje 'Ya existe el ID de esta Inspección' y no tengo más registros en las tablas, los borre todos.

Comment: Listo muchas gracias por tu ayuda, ya me funciono perfecto. :)